# Validating Password in Single Text Field Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsuserdefaults

This is main story board of my app:

[image]

I have an iOS app where I have to change the text inside the label from "Set Passcode" to "Confirm Passcode" after entry of 4 digits and then clear the text field. The passcode input is done through clicking the buttons.

Now, I have to give the 4 digits again and compare both the entries using user defaults. I know how to this using two text fields but do not know how to achieve it using single textfield.

Comment: You better not put an app storing a passcode in NSUserDefaults in the app store...

Comment: You can store your password in variable. If you tap your button store input in private variable, clear text field, change label text. 
In your tapButton method test if you have stored first password. If it is compare two inputs and password stored in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a Label, TextField and a Button, Add them all to your view controller and create a IBAction for the Button. In the Attribute Inspector set the tag number of the button to 2, you can also change the TextFields Keyboard type to Number Pad.

[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Q8cm.png)

Now add three variables:

```
var Password1: String?
var Password2: String?
var Offical_Password: String?
```

In the ViewDidLoad function set the buttons tag equal to 1:

```
Button.tag = 1
```

These two functions shown below will handle the settings of the TextField and the  Label. It will also check whether Password1 is equal to Password2 and then set the Official_Password:

```
    func Password () {
    if (TextField.text == "") {
        // Password is required
    } else {
        Lable.text = "Confirm Password"
        Password1 = TextField.text
        TextField.text = ""
    }
}


func Password_Confimed () {
    if TextField.text == "" {
        // Confirmation Password is required
    } else {
        Password2 = TextField.text
    }
    if Password1 == Password2 {
        Lable.text = "Done"
        Offical_Password = Password1
        TextField.text = ""
    } else {
        // Handle error
    }
}
```

Finally in the IBAction function add:

```
@IBAction func Button_Pressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    if Button.tag == 1 {
        Password()
        Button.tag = 2
    } else if Button.tag == 2 {
        Password_Confimed()
        // Go to another View Controller
    }
}
```

[The Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJN4v.jpg)

You will have to add how you want to deal with problems such as making sure the password isn't too weak and what you actually want to do when the password is set.

Comment: thanks for the code.. @Andrew Montague

Comment: If this worked for you, then please mark it as the correct answer @SaiPavanParanam

Comment: your code worked for me... but i dont have enough popularity to vote your answer. Sorry for not voting. I really appreciate your help. Thank you